# Accessing a username and password protected URL of an Apache server

Tags: java, android

When i try to hit the `url` from browser it shows me a pop up that wants username and password from user.

Image of browser interaction

[image]

How i can access this url by providing correct username and password from android?
I am seeking for java solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This URL is protected with username and password in header.

In android you have to code like below to acces the url and get data from it.

```
String authToken = Credentials.basic(API_USER_NAME, API_PASSWORD);
```